# Setting highest value in row to 1 and rest to 0 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

My original dataframe looks like this :

```
A       B       C
0.10    0.83    0.07
0.40    0.30    0.30
0.70    0.17    0.13    
0.72    0.04    0.24    
0.15    0.07    0.78
```

I would like that each row becomes binarized : 1 would be assigned to the column with the highest value and the rest would be set to 0, so the previous dataframe would become :

```
A   B   C
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   0   0   
1   0   0   
0   0   1
```

How can this be done ?
Thanks.

EDIT : I understand that a specific case made my question ambiguous. I should've said that in case 3 columns are equal for a given row, I'd still want to get a [1 0 0] vector and not [1 1 1] for that row.

Comment: How do you treat a column like `0.333, 0.333, 0.333`?

Comment: I don't think such problem could arise given the float precision that I have in my dataframe. But if it happens, I wouldn't mind assigning the '1' randomly to one of the three columns and rest to 0.

Comment: If you don't have any duplicates, you can just do `== max()` (and then astype it/multiply by 1/whatever). If you do have duplicates, and want to choose one at random rather than setting them all equal to 1, it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: Notice that almost all of the answers people are giving you are just some variant of `== max()`. Because the only place you hinted that may not be what you want is in a comment. You really need to edit the question to be unambiguous.

Comment: @abarnert : I'm not sure what you mean ? The solutions that have been given were really satisfying and solved my problem. Are you talking about editing to add that if for a row the three columns are duplicated I'd want one only to be equal to 1 ?

Comment: @MhamedJabri You accepted my answer, but it is wrong (see comments). If you unaccept it, I can delete it.

Comment: @MhamedJabri Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about. As user implied and I explained, the easiest solutions are all going to give you mulitple `1` values if there are duplicates. And the answers below, except for chrisz's `argmax` one, all do exactly that.

Comment: @abarnert You're right, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using **`numpy`** with **`argmax`**

```
m = np.zeros_like(df.values)
m[np.arange(len(df)), df.values.argmax(1)] = 1

df1 = pd.DataFrame(m, columns = df.columns).astype(int)

# Result


   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  1  0  0
4  0  0  1
```

***Timings***

```
df_test = df.concat([df] * 1000)

def chris_z(df):
     m = np.zeros_like(df.values)
     m[np.arange(len(df)), df.values.argmax(1)] = 1
     return pd.DataFrame(m, columns = df.columns).astype(int)

def haleemur(df):
    return df.apply(lambda x: x == x.max(), axis=1).astype(int)

def haleemur_2(df):
    return pd.DataFrame((df.T == df.T.max()).T.astype(int), columns=df.columns)

def sacul(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.T == df.T.max(), 1, 0),index=df.columns).T
```

***Results***

```
In [320]: %timeit chris_z(df_test)
358 µs ± 1.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [321]: %timeit haleemur(df_test)
1.14 s ± 45.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [329]: %timeit haleemur_2(df_test)
972 µs ± 11.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [333]: %timeit sacul(df_test)
1.01 ms ± 3.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: You probably want `m` to be bool, no?

Comment: The `argmax` solution is the only one that's (at least arguably) correct for duplicates, as well as being fastest.

Answer (score 4):

```
 df.apply(lambda x: x == x.max(), axis=1).astype(int)
```

should do it. This works by checking if the value is the maximum of that column, and then casting to integer (True -> 1, False -> 0)

Instead of `apply`-ing a lambda row-wise, it is also possible to transpose the dataframe & compare to `max` and then transpose back

```
(df.T == df.T.max()).T.astype(int)
```

And lastly, a very fast numpy based solution:

```
pd.DataFrame((df.T.values == np.amax(df.values, 1)).T*1, columns = df.columns)
```

The output is in all cases:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  1  0  0
4  0  0  1
```

Comment: This isn't giving me the correct output, it leaves rows 1 and 2 with all zeros

Comment: oh, i misread the question, you need the max comparison row-wise. updating accordingly.

Comment: @chrisz, fixed.

Comment: Your second approach is much, much faster

Comment: @chrisz, thanks for the benchmarks! I added a faster numpy-based solution, would love to see how it compares to your fast implementation on your machine.

Comment: It will be just about as fast, if not slightly faster than my approach, but again, it will return duplicated `1s` if two columns share the same value.

Answer (score 3):

Another `numpy` method, using `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.T == df.T.max(), 1, 0),index=df.columns).T
   A  B  C
0  0  1  0
1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0
3  1  0  0
4  0  0  1
```

Comment: This gives the wrong result if there are duplicates. Although the question is ambiguous about what should happen in this case, from the OP's comments it sounds like a `1 1 1` row is not acceptable.

Comment: Also, the `np.where` just adds overhead, compare the timings to @haleemur's identical answer, without `np.where` is actually faster.

Comment: I wouldn't delete, it's still a valid answer.  The question is quite ambiguous

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, it's indeed my fault. Let me edit my question first. Sorry :)

Comment: Check out `haleemur_2` vs your solution in my timings, that's all I meant by overhead.  It barely has an effect on performance